# Dispaly only terms that has posts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress post type that works with two taxonomies.
I want to display a list of all terms from taxonomy "locationcat", that uses the term "lunch" from the other taxonomy "menucat".
 Sadly, I have being able to print all terms from both toxonomies..
Here is my code:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
'hide_empty' => true,
                        'tax_query' => array(
                         'relation' => 'AND',
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'locationcat',
                            'hide_empty' => true,
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'menucat',
                                    'field'    => 'slug',
                                    'terms'    => 'lunch',
                                    'hide_empty' => true,
                            ),
                        ),
                ) );
                foreach ($terms as $sc) {
                    $link = $sc->slug;
                    echo '<li><a href="#'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a bit confusing as you are asking "Dispaly only terms that has posts in Wordpress". I assume you meant "Display posts with terms from 2 taxonomies."

If this is correct then here is your solution.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tax_1'
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'term-slug1'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tax_2',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'term-slug1'
        )
    )
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

And then proceed with your loop.

If I misunderstood your question then please try rephrasing it.